# Why isn't a variable defined by attr_accessor available in a method?

Tags: ruby

```
class A
 attr_accessor :rank
 def change_rank
   rank = rank + 1
 end
end

a = A.new
a.rank = 5
p a.rank
a.change_rank
p a.rank
```

produces an error for rank = rank + 1 (undefined method + for nil:Nilclass). Shouldn't an implicit call to the "rank" method return the value of the instance variable @rank? For some reason, this code works if I change the 4th line to:

```
self.rank = self.rank + 1
```

Why does an explicit call to the rank method works while an implicit one doesn't?

Comment: The instance variable `@rank` and local variable `rank` are as different as `@cat` and `dog`, and co-exist.  `self.rank = self.rank + 1` works because `self` equals `a`, `self.rank` is `a.rank`, which, because of `attr_accessor :rank`, is `@rank`.  So just change `rank = rank + 1` to `@rank = @rank + 1` or `@rank += @rank`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
 def change_rank
   rank = rank + 1
 end
```

In this context name `rank` does **not** resolve to one of methods generated by `attr_accessor`. It is seen by ruby roughly as this:

```
 def change_rank
   rank = nil
   rank = rank + 1
 end
```

When ruby sees an assignment to a "naked" name, it creates a local variable with this name. It will shadow the outer method. And since local vars are initialized with `nil`, it explains the error you're getting.

You can do this to avoid the error (be explicit about what you're modifying):

```
 def change_rank
   self.rank += 1
 end
```

### Update:

Here's more code that illustrates this

```
defined?(x) # => nil # name x is unidentified yet
defined?(x = x) # => "assignment" # local var x is created by assignment
defined?(x) # => "local-variable" # now local var x exists
x # => nil # and its value is nil
```

Answer (score 0):

I rewrite your code as following. You can see how Ruby treats rank= and rank with different ways.

```
class A
  attr_accessor :rank
  def change_rank
    self.rank = rank + 1
 end
end

a = A.new
a.rank = 5
p a.rank
a.change_rank
p a.rank
```

execution result:

```
5
6
```